# URLLoader security scheme

Tags: actionscript-3

As my understand, the only method to read in binary data from a remote url is through `URLLoader`.

I know that `URLRequest` takes in a context parameter which allows to ask to check for policy file (which is properly configured in my case). Although it's not very clear how to do the same with `URLLoader`.

What I am trying to achieve is to load a WAV file from my S3 bucket. I tried with mp3 which uses `URLRequest` on the same bucket and it worked fine.

Should I look for an alternative way of loading the binary data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do but you can load your WAV file through [`Sound#load()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29).

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/1.wav");
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(1000, true);
var sound:Sound = new Sound();

sound.load(request);
```

---

Alternatively you can have try [AS3WavSound](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/).

Comment: I was under the impression that flash does not support wav as a sound object .. i will try now

Comment: yeah as i thought .. it didn't work .. thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: according to this: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/media/quick-tip-play-external-wav-files-in-as3/ , it still needs a URLLoader, which in turns still needs a policy in order to load. It seems to be developed in the aim of allowing people who use flex import/load from same domain